# Android Smack with MVP fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvp, smack, mosby

I am using smack (XMPP library) and [Mosby's](https://github.com/sockeqwe/mosby) `MvpFagment` to show the roster of a user in a listview (his/her connections).

I got the following code which works in a different fragment just doing a network call using the Retrofit library:

```
public void loadListData(final List<NeighbourListItemModel> itemsList) {
    Log.e("list", itemsList.size() + "");
    listViewAdapter.clear();
    listViewAdapter.addThemAll(itemsList);
    listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Which gets called by a `RosterListener` using `roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() { .. });`

The `NeighbourListItemModel` is just a simple POJO class having some getters and setts.

However, this gives a `AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Exception in async packet listener
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` error, probably because the XMP connection runs in its own thread.

Now if I change the code to the following:

```
@Override
public void loadListData(final List<NeighbourListItemModel> itemsList) {
    Log.e("list", itemsList.size() + "");
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listViewAdapter.clear();
            listViewAdapter.addThemAll(itemsList);
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int getLayout()' on a null object reference` error. Where getLayout is defined in:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderAbstractClass viewHolder;
        if (null == convertView || null == convertView.getTag()) {
            viewHolder = getItem(position).getDefaultViewHolder(mItemType);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(viewHolder.getLayout(), null);
            viewHolder.findViewsById(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderAbstractClass) convertView.getTag();
        }

        BaseModel previousItem = position > 0 ? getItem(position - 1) : null;
        viewHolder.setup(getItem(position), previousItem, mCaller.getContext(), position);

        return convertView;
    }
```

The view holder abstract class is nothing special:

```
public abstract class ViewHolderAbstractClass {

    abstract public int getLayout();

    abstract public void findViewsById(View view);

    abstract public void initializeComponentBehavior(BaseModel item, Context context, int position);

    public void setup(BaseModel item, BaseModel previous_item, Context context, int position) {
        initializeComponentBehavior(item, context, position);
    }

}
```

So obviously the `viewHolder` variable is null, but I have no idea why. My adapter is defined as `new BaseListAdapter(this, R.layout.neighbours_list_item, new ArrayList<ChatItemModel>(), Constants.DATA_TYPE.CHAT);`

Like I said, the former code is working when I make a call using Retrofit, but I suspect XMPP running in its own thread is giving me headaches.

Comment: I never used MVP. But I don't see code for the abstract getLayout().

Comment: I like to know. Why do you use Mosby's MvpFagment? As in any library, staying compatible with the framework like Android is always an issue.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid Unfortuntely it was not my decision as I am working on existing code. I would've done it differently but it would mean that I have to tear this app apart.So far it gave me a few headaches.

The getLayout function just retuns R.id.<layout>, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the `Constants.DATA_TYPE itemType` was referring to another model instead of a `NeighbourListItemModel` which caused a null return. The stacktrace did not show this clearly, but at least it is solved now.

Comment: btw. Mosby assumes that all interaction from Presenter to View happens on the main ui thread. you should consider to invoke `loadListData()` from presentet on main ui thread instead of runOnUiThread() in View

Answer (score 0):

1)  I think this code `viewHolder = getItem(position).getDefaultViewHolder(mItemType)` is a suspect. It seems the code is caching the `ViewHolder` class and the problem is you cannot cache or save the UI IDs. I am sure you notice other developers simply create an instance of `ViewHolder`.

Besides that, please post code for getDefaultViewHolder.

2)  Another, I suspect `findViewsById`() method could not work because it seems it is trying to cache UI IDs to find the correct View object.

** This issue of caching UI IDs is more noticeable now (!) because you are getting IDs on a separate thread.

You may however update the UI views on a separate UI thread. And you can get the UI IDs on a separate thread, but don't cache it, use it right away.